# PHP league/csv Reader How to know which delimiter was used?

Tags: php, symfony, csv, vendor, vendors

When using league/csv to read a csv file, how could I know which csv controls have been used to parse the file ?

I made different csv files :

- delimiter_colon.csv  {exported from excel with colon delimiter}
- delimiter_tab.csv  {exported from excel with tab delimiter}
- delimiter_semicolon.csv {exported from excel with semicolon delimiter}
- etc...

When using

```
use League\Csv\Reader;
...

//Read csv from path
$csvReader = Reader::createFromPath( $CSVFile->path );

//get the current delimiter ? Nope always the default one ...
$this->delimiter = $csvReader->getDelimiter();
```

**EDIT:** What I want to know is which delimiter has been used by the current reader. 
Not the delimiter in the csv file itself.

Whatever the file I use to read the csv, it always gives "," {coma}
So I'm asking here:

How to know which delimiter/enclosure were used to parse the current csv Reader ?

I've also tried using getIterator(). Get default values too.

Comment: Are you expecting the different file names to change the delimiter setting?

Comment: Not the filename themselves. Each file has been exported from excel with different csv delimiter. Im expected the Reader to tell me which delimiter he used to parse the file.

Comment: I edited the post, to make it clearer about the delimiter in the files.

Comment: The CSV files don't contain an actual reference to the delimiter used so there is no way for the script to know beyond guessing which, I can only assume, would be more error prone than useful . Unless you change the delimiter using `$csvReader->setDelimiter($newDelimiter)` it will stay as the default `,`.

Comment: I understand you, but actually I want to know which delimiter has been used by the current reader.

Comment: Unless you change it, the delimiter will be `,`. So, providing you just use `$reader = Reader::createFromPath($path)` the delimiter will remain `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of the library you can simply use [Reader::fetchDelimitersOccurrence](http://csv.thephpleague.com/properties/#fetchdelimitersoccurrence) as explained in the documentation. But be aware that the method will only return information about the suggested delimiters you supply. Because it is not possible for the method to know which delimiter is in use. The result is only a hint that needs to be confirm by the CSV provider.

Comment: This answer clarify my understanding about the way Reader works. Thanks.